# Cyanogenmod 13 get rid of Google bar

Tags: cyanogenmod, google

I recently updated my Galaxy S5 to Cyanogenmod 13 and have this annoying Google search bar on the top of my home screen. I used to be able to get rid of this in CM 12 but can't find how to do it in CM 13. Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Trebuchet (the default launcher)? Long press empty space on homescreen, tap the little up arrow on the bottom, then find this and turn off.

[image]

Screenshot captured on my own Nexus 6P with CM13.